# Malware able to "read" one's screen

Tags: malware, multi-factor

I was searching online about multifactor authentication. One of the reasons that people recommend it is because they fear someone may use a keylogger to "steal" their password, so they use one more step to be safe.

What I am wondering is if there is some kind of malware that is able to "read" someone's screen or take screenshots of it, making some multifactor authentication services vulnerable.

In order to explain what kind of services I mean, a lot of times a multifactor authentication service doesn't use another device to authenticate, but sends either a code to the same device or the user has to use a message that the service has generated for him. So if the malware can capture the screen the attacker can read those.

If there is a malware that is capable of something like that how can someone protect from it?

Comment: How would being able to see the screen make MFA vulnerable?

Comment: @schroeder A lot of times a service that uses multifactor authentication doesn't use another device to authenticate, but sends either a code to the same device or the user has to use a message that the service has generated for him. So if the malware can capture the screen the attacker can read those.

Comment: I have honestly never heard of such a MFA mechanism. All MFA functions I know are performed in a secondary channel, for precisely the concerns you outline in your question.

Comment: @schroeder That is one of the mechanisms that LastPass proposes to the users, the one called Grid. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> malware that is able to "read" someone's screen or take screenshots of it, making even the usage of multifactor authentication vulnerable.

There is a wide variety of legal and illegal remote access software which enable the attacker to fully control the system, see the remote desktop etc. Some banking trojans integrate this facility to work around onscreen-keyboards the user might use. There are also mobile applications which capture the SMS used sometimes in 2FA or online banking.

> If there is a malware that is capable of something like that how can someone protect from it?

There is no special way just for this kind of malware. This means the same protections are used as against other kind of malware. And same as with other malware you have to be aware that no antivirus or whatever security product will catch every malware.  Thus for best security use dedicates machines which are only used for this specific task (like online banking) and where you don't do normal surfing, mail reading, ..., i.e. all the ways how malware usually spreads.

There are also [hardware products](https://www.google.com/search?q=2fa+token) which can be used together with 2FA and which are not affected by malware because they just have this single purpose minimal system which cannot be simply updated to integrate malicious functionality. Using these for 2FA is more expensive but also more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Malware can read CAPTCHA which can used as part of multifaceted authentication.

It's also possible to install software on a user's machine to create an RDP style session and spy on someone. A key logging virus can capture your key strokes and send the contents to a remote destination. So many ways exist to obtain multifaceted authentication data within a limited scope. So Multi factor authentication is vulnerable to a degree, however the goal with a good multi factor implementation is to make it as difficult as possible for the attacker to get into your system. In other words, you want to harden the multi factor authentication process as much as one reasonably can as the bad guys want easier targets because time, money and system resources need to be spent wisely by the bad guys so they can maximize the time they put into their crime.

Also security is best thought of as an onion. So before I would be concerned with multi factor authentication I'd fully asses my current security posture from the outside world in and back. Nothing is impenetrable as I've mentioned it's truly about eliminating as many potential attack vectors for the bad guys so they give up and move on.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be about "multifaceted" authentication but "multifactor". CAPTCHA is not a factor in MFA. Also, although you are talking about MFA security in general, you don't address the actual question asked (being able to see the screen), except a note about RDP.

Comment: You're correct. My apologies. Multi factor authentication is difficult to break but not impossible. It's also possible to monitor what somebody is doing on a PC or any device with a screen without their knowledge if someone has the software to do it. I've not heard of any bot type of malware that exists currently that allows this to happen without a person sitting behind a keyboard and mouse.